# How to find a group of similar topics from keywords in Python?

Tags: nlp, nltk, lda, text-classification, topic-modeling

Using Python's NLTK, I managed to extract unigrams, bigrams, trigrams and quadgrams from a blog post. I put in into perspective with the whole website's content to find the right topic(s) discussed in the given blog article.

I end up with a result such as **article_topic = ['dog breeding']**

Now, what is the right or best way to use that 'dog breeding' term and find related terms of similar length such as, for example, dog breeding program, breeding dogs, canine reproduction, etc.

Is there an API or Library helping with this?

Answer (score 0):

Well if you want to classify documents based on a topic then one way to move further is use Clustering .

So I was given a similar problem with a dataset of few hundred documents. 
Also I was given all topics to create cluster.

Working - After Clustering is done , for any cluster , All documents in that cluster are closely related to each other since clustering was done based on topics found in them.

How to -
**So the instructions I followed were:**
1) Represent each document in vector form using tf-idf notation [Link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tf%E2%80%93idf) 
2) Use the vector form you got above to run K-Means Clustering Algorithm 
3) Finally Any new document you get just keep adding it into clusters.
4) Now you can tell that topics in a cluster are closely related , hence your new document can be classified in one/more of the topics .

For more info - 
 [Link](http://scikitlearn.org/stable/auto_examples/text/document_clustering.html)

Answer (score 0):

you can use the very popular semantic vectors ( or word2vec). Using this model, you can easily make an inference to obtains the most similar words (or topics) based on the training set. You can obtain a google pre-trained model with 1 billion of English words. However, you also can train you own model using the tags of your blog (it makes sense to me).

You can do it using Gensin library.
https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/word2vec.html

Answer (score 0):

If i have understood your question correctly, you have topics for each article and now you want to select other keywords which are more close to the respective article topics.

You can achieve this in two steps:

- Step 1: Select the top `k` terms based on `tf-idf` weight from an article and they should be more close to the article topic.
- Step 2: Cluster all the articles which share the same topic and then do the same thing explained in step 1.

Since you already know the topics of your articles, there is no point of using topic modeling methods. Perhaps, you can use word embedding techniques but then you have to re-design your topic inference part. This would be difficult if you don't have sufficient knowledge about word embedding techniques like CBOW or skip-gram model. (I don't want to recommend this for your target task)

I would rather recommend you to use good feature extraction technique with some clustering-based approach and i believe you will get pretty good result. You can consider some good metric like [mutual information](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutual_information) which can tell you if two keywords share some information and should be grouped together.

Lastly, you can also use some dictionary based approach to compute semantic relatedness between keywords. For example, you can use [WordNet](https://wordnet.princeton.edu/) and then score keyword pairs based on their relationship according to WordNet hierarchy. [WordNet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WordNet) is a very good resource for structured knowledge. See this [example](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/11835/WordNet-based-semantic-similarity-measurement) for details. You can use [Java API for WordNet Searching](https://github.com/agreementmaker/jaws) or [WordNet NLTK Interface](http://www.nltk.org/howto/wordnet.html) and both of them are pretty simple to use (I have used before).

You can compute WordNet similarity (pairwise), so that each word/topic is represented as a vector of distances, which could then be discretized, so each vector would have a form like this: `[0,2,3,1,0,0,2,1,3,...]`. These vectors could then be clustered using one of the methods in the [NLTK cluster package](http://www.nltk.org/api/nltk.cluster.html) or [scikit-learn cluster package](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/clustering.html).

I believe you will get sufficiently good result with these suggested approaches.